# How to add missing maven libraries to Jetty

Tags: java, xml, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to launch a maven project, that I always launched manually in Tomcat, in Jetty. For this I am using the maven-jetty-plugin.

When executing jetty:run It seems like everything goes fine, except for the fact that Jetty does not find the dependencies defined in the POM.

If I run jetty:war, the war is built properly, using the dependencies, so that works. Why is jetty:run not including my libraries in WEB-INF/lib (or anywhere else)?

Comment: What is the "scope" of missing dependencies?

Comment: @BenoitCourtine, I defined no scope.

Comment: I am also having this problem, using Maven 2 with jetty-maven-plugin 7.5.2. If I use jetty:run, the application gives ClassNotFoundException and NoClassDefFoundError. If I use jetty:run-war, everything is fine. Also, if I copy the dependency to the plugin's dependency list (so that it's on the container's classpath), jetty:run works. My dependencies are on third-party artifacts that Maven has already downloaded to my local repo.
Would love to hear from anyone who knows why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a dependency for Jetty which resides somewhere other than the main Maven repo, add the following:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repo-id</id>
        <url>http://my_other_repo.edu</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I don't believe Jetty will use the existing repositories in your POM.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the dependencies you have defined. For example, if you have defined a JNDI resource in your jetty.xml file, you will need the `jetty-plus` dependency. However, you will need this dependency for the execution of the plugin only. Plugins can have `<dependencies/>` and that is where you need to define it.

If you have a list of Jetty-specific classes that the plugin can't find, the best way to look up the dependencies is to use a site like www.jarvana.com.

Comment: I dont use any jetty specific classes. I migrated from tomcat, so I have absolutely nothing jetty specific. I do not hava a jetty.xml either...

Answer (score 0):

By 'dependencies', do you mean other projects?

If so, you will need to install (mvn:install) these into the local repository before jetty:run will see them.

It's possible that jetty:war is packaging them and placing them into the lib folder without installing into the local repo.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had one .jar file in my repo that was not getting picked up by Eclipse.  I didn't figure out how to fix it in Eclipse, so my work around was to ...

1. Add a duplicate of the .jar file to the repo under a different groupId (different path under ~/.m2) using this command:

   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=dhcp4java-1.0.0.jar -DgroupId=a_abc.hack -DartifactId=dhcp4java -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
2. Reference the new groupId , which requires only to update this entry for the dependency in pom.xml :

   <groupId>a_abc.hack </groupId>